# Applying scale to rigged model breaks animations

Tags: animation, rigging, gltf

An artist made me an aniamted model, but the model is 50 units tall, when I need it to be around 2 units tall.

I am trying to resize it, this is the originial:

[image]

I select the armature and the model and press `S`.

[image]

I make them much smaller (you can see the cube now, it;s in all the images but that's how large the model was):

[image]

At this point if I play an animation all is fine, they play properly at the scale I want, but if I delete the armature the model becomes big again:

[image]

So I select both and apply location and rotation

[image]

Now I can delete the armature and the model is the right size, and the animations still play properly.

[image]

However if I export this model in this state to gltf, reimport and delete the armature again the model becomes gigantic again.

If I try to apply scale to the model:

[image]

These black lines appear and the animation breaks in horrible horrible ways by having the model move around and teleport without logic.

[image]

Why can't I export the model at the current scale? The animations work just fine in blender before exporting and everything looks correct. But as soon as it's exported it all breaks and I can't apply scaling because it also breaks.

Comment: Ideally (1) the mesh is a child of the arma, and (2) both mesh and arma have Loc=0, Rot=0, Scale=1. I would try selecting only the arma, scaling it down to the desired size, then selecting both arma and mesh, and applying all transforms. Then try exporting.

Comment: As suggested I scaled only the armature and then did ctrl + a and applied the scale. When i do that the animations break fro some reason :C

Comment: Attach the .blend.

Comment: blend exchange only allows up to 30 MB and my blend is 74MB I can't .

Comment: then just use any other cloud platform like dropbox or whatever...